# OpenNTF Domino API (ODA) WrapperFactory.fromLotus Usage

Tags: xpages

I have a situation where I need to get a `org.openntf.domino.Document` object from a `lotus.domino.Document` object. I found examples using `Factory.fromLotus()` but this is depreciated.

The JavaDocs pointed me to `WrapperFactory.fromLotus()` but I am unsure how to use this. I am currently doing this:

`Document doc = WrapperFactory.fromLotus(lotusDoc, org.openntf.domino.Document.class, null);`

Eclipse is marking this line with an error:

> The method fromLotus(D, FactorySchema, P) in the type
>   WrapperFactory is not applicable for the arguments (Document,
>   Class, null)

How do I use `WrapperFactory.fromLotus()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method wants the original Lotus object (as you're doing), a "schema" object, and then the parent.

For the schema, you can use org.openntf.domino.Document.SCHEMA.

For the parent, you'll need to pass in a wrapped version of the parent Database object. I believe can go up the chain by getting the Database and then the Session - wrap the session with `Session s = fac.fromLotus(lotusSession, Session.SCHEMA, null)`, then the DB with `Database db = fac.fromLotus(lotusDatabase, Database.SCHEMA, s)`, then the doc with `Document doc = fac.fromLotus(lotusDoc, Document.SCHEMA, db)`.

Comment: For the parent I was able to just use null. I assume it just uses the current Database when this parameter is null.